# Beautiful soup getting the next span element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have problems to get the data I want from beautiful soup. I have the following html page:

```
<br/>
<h4>Dieses Jahr</h4>
<br/>
<span class="parName">Diesen Monat:</span> <span class="parValue">67.54 kWh</span> | 
<span class="parName">Januar:</span> <span class="parValue">143.92 kWh</span> | 
<span class="parName">Februar:</span> <span class="parValue">350.51 kWh</span> |
```

I need to access the value in the 2nd span 67.54 kWh (after the span with "Diesen Monat:".
Im able to access the "Diesen Monat" span and thought I could use next sibling from there, but this does not work.

```
find("span", string="Diesen Monat:").next_sibling
```

Any idea what I do not get right with beautiful soup

Answer (score 0):

`.next_sibling` gets the next child [from the parent tag], which isn't necessarily a tag. In this case, it's probably an empty [NavigableString](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring). To get the next sibling *Tag*, use [`.find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) instead

```py
html = '''
<br/>
<h4>Dieses Jahr</h4>
<br/>
<span class="parName">Januar:</span> <span class="parValue">143.92 kWh</span> | 
<span class="parName">Diesen Monat:</span> <span class="parValue">67.54 kWh</span> | 
<span class="parName">Februar:</span> <span class="parValue">350.51 kWh</span> | 
'''
BeautifulSoup(html).find("span", string="Diesen Monat:").find_next_sibling()
```

returns `<span class="parValue">67.54 kWh</span>`.

---

Btw, if you have [html5lib](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/) parser installed, you can do it with a single `select_one` call

```py
BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib').select_one("span:-soup-contains('Diesen Monat:') + span")
```